# Predeclare subclasses

Tags: c++, subclass, declaration

This is my situation:

```
class foo{
public:
    class bar{
        friend bar operator+(const bar & , int i);
    }
};
foo::bar operator+(const foo::bar & , int i){
   ...
}
```

if i compile this i get an error `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64...` so what i've done is this:

```
foo::bar operator+(const bar & , int i);
class foo{
public:
    class bar{
        friend bar operator+(const bar & , int i);
    }
};
foo::bar operator+(const foo::bar & , int i){
   ...
}
```

But now is the declaration that doesn't know what is `foo::bar` so i've added this:

```
class foo{
public:
    class bar;
}
foo::bar operator+(const bar & , int i);
class foo{
public:
    class bar{
        friend bar operator+(const bar & , int i);
    }
};
foo::bar operator+(const foo::bar & , int i){
   ...
}
```

But now is telling me that i'm redefining the class `foo`, how can i solve this?

Also tried

```
class foo::bar;
```

at the beginning, but it doesn't work

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot forward-declare inner classes in C++. You have to un-nest one of the inner classes, so that it can be declared independently. Maybe replace the inner class with a `typedef`, so as far as the class is concerned, it's an inner class.

Comment: Forward declaration issues will cause compile-time errors, not link-time errors about "undefined symbols". The examples you show (obviously not actually tried) don't explain that piece.